# How to setup jquery plugin into my codeigniter project using eclipse-mars IDE

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, eclipse, codeigniter

I have downloaded **jquery-validation-1.14.0.zip** file from web. And know I am trying to use it in my project, but the problem with me is i don't know exactly where to place the folder(extracted file) in my wamp folder, and what are the changes to be made on any of the config or .htaccess file. As i have given all my complete 3-4 days to configure it by my own, but finally left with no options and i am posting my question here so that anyone here can help me out.
basically here is my 
**folder sructure;-**
C:\wamp\www\developer\jquery-validation

**controller**:-
 C:\wamp\www\developer\application\controllers

**How do i use to call the script file in my view:-**

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src ="../jquery-validation/lib/jquery.js">      </script>
<script  type="text/javascript" src ="../jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.js"> </script>
</head>
```

And another thing that i would like to emphasis here is, in eclipse-mars, i have included jquery library too. And now i have jquery 2.0 library inside Javascript Resources.

After doing all these when i simply try to use alert function, i got to see lots of errors.
**Errors:-**
GET 
http://localhost/developer/index.php/jquery-validation/lib/jquery.js  [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 27ms] 
GET 
http://localhost/developer/index.php/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.js [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 30ms] 
ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Please get me rid of all these anyhow.. Now i'm totally frustrated..
Very Very Thanks in advance..

the problem remains the same @praveen and @ ichadhr. For more clarification of my code, here is a simple view:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src ="<?php echo base_url('jquery-validation/lib/jquery.js');?>" ></script>
<script  type="text/javascript" src ="<?php echo base_url('jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.js');?>"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" id="myform">
<div class="form-group">
<label for="name">Name:</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name">
</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="sub">Submit</button>
</form>

<script>
$("#sub").click(function(){
    alert("hello");
    $("#myform").valid();
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

And my base url is localhost/developer 
and the folder and file locations for js file are as in my code. 
Errors are still same

Comment: try this `<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url("/jquery-validation/lib/jquery.js");?>"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

All included assets bind with

```
base_url('path/to/script.js');
```

And all links generate with

```
site_url('controller/action/param');
```

Answer (score 0):

After Seeing your new description assuming files are in your views folder inside application So the becomes  :-

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src ="<?php echo base_url('jquery-validation/lib/jquery.js');?>" ></script>
<script  type="text/javascript" src ="<?php echo base_url('jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.js');?>"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" id="myform">
<div class="form-group">
<label for="name">Name:</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name">
</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="sub">Submit</button>
</form>

<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
$("#sub").click(function(){
    alert("hello");
});
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: refer to above the more clear description that i have added.

Comment: @PratikLalan check now

Comment: i know the code is simple to achive, but can you let me know is there any pre-configuration that is needed in order to deal with jquery? Either in config,htacces etc files. As i already have done few configurations, but in case i might be missing some. 
(error remains same, like jquery is not defined)

Comment: and thank you praveen for your consistance help. @Praveen Kumar

Comment: welcome @PratikLalan open your jquery.js in browser and if the url is something like **file:///C:/wamp/www/developer/jquery-validation/lib/jquery.js** then put part after **file:///C:/wamp/www/developer/** (in this case that is **jquery-validation/lib/jquery.js**) into base_url('jquery-validation/lib/jquery.js') just like this :)